# Arrow keys do not work with firebase init command

Tags: firebase

```
$ firebase init
!  Caution! Initializing outside your home directory
? What Firebase do you want to use? (Use arrow keys)
```

I tried to press arrow keys but nothing is happening. How can I select an existing firebase app while doing `firebase init`?

Comment: What version of the Firebase-CLI and Node are you running?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: Only works in the windows cmd or powershell window.  Does not work in with cygwin or git bash.

Comment: Also don't work on mac terminal

Comment: Use numbers to select the item, for example: second arrowed pointed item can be refered as 2.

Answer (score 12):

When [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/) let me down:

[image]

CMD did the job:

[image]

Comment: Yep, same here, but this is a bug I have encountered with other CLI node applications

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue. Downgrading firebase-tools version to 6.0.0 worked for me. Currently, the latest version is 7.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

The Firebase CLI interface has changed my original response below no longer works.

The good news it that this now seems to work normally in the windows console. Tested with Windows 10, firebase-tools 3.0.8 and Node 6.10.0.

You can skip the initial radio box feature selection by specifying one or both of `database` or `hosting` after `init`. E.g:

```
> firebase init database
```

Using `-P <project-name>` to specify the project name doesn't seem to work for `init` though and it still prompts...

**Original answer:**

I just ran into this. Use:

```
> firebase init -f <name-of-firebase>
```

To get a list of all command line options:

```
> firebase init -h
```

Comment: works w/`use` cmd as well , eg `firebase use --add --interactive <name-of-firebase>` . cool, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also was stuck with this issue yesterday .Today this has been fixed in firebase-tools version 7.0.1 .
Reinstall or update firebase-tools and hopefully the problem vanishes for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update your NodeJs version to use arrow keys on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't working while using the bash and cmd terminals. Only worked with the Powershell terminal

Answer (score -1):

It should work if you use a newer vesion of NodeJS.

I use version 6.10.2 run in 'bash on windows'.

AND! I use 'windows creators update' to get the leatest version of windows 10.